# A box has 100 different balls. No of Balls that can be selected = 1 to 100. How many ways can we select?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, permutations, combinations, balls-in-bins

A box have 100 balls. Each one is different. One boy can take atleast 1, atmost 100 balls. How many WAYS can he take balls ?

( clarification: Taking ball 1 then ball 2 = Taking ball 2 then ball 1 )

Comment: Try with a small number, like 3 balls, then 4 to see how that goes...

Comment: This is unclear. Is taking ball $1$ then ball $2$ the same thing as taking ball $2$ then ball $1$ ?

Comment: taking ball 1 then ball 2 = taking ball 2 then ball 1....

Comment: You seem to have caused some confusion with the phrase "*balls can be replaced each time*"... what do you mean by this explicitly?  Are you suggesting that ball 1 can be picked multiple times?  So... for instance one of the options is  `1,1,1,2,1,2,2,2`?  And then with the next line implying order doesn't matter, so this is the same as `1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2`?  Or was taking the same ball multiple times within the same drawing not allowed?

Comment: I didn't mean that. First, the boy can choose 100 balls. Then he put the ball back in the box. Next boy can choose 5 balls, like that...

Comment: So... for a much smaller problem if there were only three balls available rather than 100... the full list would be the $2^3-1=8-1=7$ options: `1,2,3,12,13,23,123` yes?  Where we explicitly write each outcome with the balls in increasing order to avoid accidental overcounting... `21` already existing in that list having been written as `12`.  And we aren't missing any like `11` or `333` etc...  If so, then this is indeed just a subset-counting problem as the first user attempted to answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each ball is either picked or not, so for each ball we have two possibilities, and so the total number of possible draws is $2^{100}$.

From that we need to subtract *one* way of picking where none of the balls got picked.

This leaves us with $2^{100}-1$ ways altogether.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint :** The number of subsets of a $n$-elements set is $2^n$ (why and what is the link with the original question ?)

Comment: This can be heavily simplified via the hockey-stick identity, or even easier by using an additional placeholder variable counting the number of the 100 allotted draws which were left unused.

Comment: Now... as context clues and clarification from the OP signify however, this *does* appear to be simply the subset-counting question just awkwardly worded.

Comment: Downvoting an answer because the OP's question is unclear is interesting.

Comment: I could say the same to you, presumably having been the one to downvote Robby's answer first.  In any case, no... I didn't downvote because OP's question being unclear, I downvoted because OP's question *was* clear and it was not in line with what your post was an answer to.  You can always spend more time in the comments section of the question itself continuing to ask for clarification before writing an answer, as I had, to be sure that there is no remaining ambiguity.  I had not downvoted until the ambiguity had been removed.

Comment: "Who is Robby?"  The answerer who posted before you which you commented `The OP says that balls can be replaced at each step. – TheSilverDoe 17 mins ago` on their now deleted but correct answer.

Comment: I agree, it was a great answer.